# Disallow evaluation of 'undefined result' in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, clang, webassembly

The following code is compiled by clang to wasm platform:

```
uint64_t Get() const
{
    uint32_t ord = -m_Order;
    if (ord >= 64)
        return 0;

    return m_Num >> ord;
}
```

The compiled wasm code (with optimizations enabled) turns out to be like this:

```
        i64.const 0

        local.get $l4
        i32.const 0
        local.get $p2
        i32.sub
        local.tee $l5
        i64.extend_i32_u
        i64.shr_u

        local.get $l5
        i32.const 63
        i32.gt_u
        select
```

As we can see, the expression `m_Num >> ord` is always evaluated, however the end result would be either it, or `0` (the very first command places it on the operand stack).

We run the resulting wasm code on our virtual machine. The problem is: when `-m_Order` is greater than 63, the program crashes (i.e. trapped, there's no crash of virtual machine), because shift operation by more bits than the operand size is considered an undefined behavior.

According to LLVM docs this is NOT undefined behavior, it's just undefined result (so-called poison value).

So, my question is: is there a possibility to prevent LLVM from doing this optimization? I.e. disallow for the optimizer to produce undefined results, that were not meant to be produced by the original code?

**Update:**

Clarification: as discovered, the WebAssembly standard explicitly **allows** this. For bit shift operators bit shift count can be bigger than the max number of bits, in this case the shift count must be treated modulo max number of bits (similar to how x86 processors handle this). So it's even not undefined result.

So it's a problem of our virtual machine, it has a deviation from the standard. Fixing this is not a problem, but upgrading the whole system is problematic, so we prefer to keep the current behavior atm. We need a sort of a workaround for the problem.

One solution that I've found is calling some 3rd-party dummy function inside the `if` block, this will enforce the compiler to generate proper branching, instead of calculating all the variants and choosing the right one via `select`. I mean this:

```
uint64_t Get() const
{
    uint32_t ord = -m_Order;
    if (ord >= 64)
    {
        DummyFunction(); // this is the workaround
        return 0;
    }

    return m_Num >> ord;
}
```

But I'd like to have a more elegant solution. After all, the LLVM should be very flexible in this respect. It contains somewhere the exact definition of the target platform, among other things there're definitions of how it handles bit shifts. Perhaps modifications can be done there.

Comment: I'd describe this as a bug in the LLVM back end for wasm; it should not be speculatively executing an instruction that can trap.  Have you talked to the LLVM people about this?

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not a bug. As discovered, WebAssembly explicitly permits this. Moreover, it's even not an undefined behavior, according to WebAssembly shift operation should treat the bit count modulo max number of bits

Comment: @Valto Then that means the crash is a bug in your VM, doesn't it?

Comment: @zwol yes, it's indeed a bug in our virtual machine. Fixing the bug is easy, however doing the system upgrade is a hassle, so we're looking for a sort of a workaround.

Comment: How about disabling optimisation just for that one function?  There's a `#pragma` for that, IIRC.  Or do you have this happening all over the place?